# Is it possible to configure dead key in XKB keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb, input-method

Unlike `Compose key`, I want to set any character as a *dead key*. It generates a *third character* after pressing a specific key after the dead key.

This dead key feature is available in `ibus-m17n`, but I did not find in `XKB`.

Comment: I don’t get what the meaningful distinction between the two is.  A dead-key works like a particular-purpose compose key (less mappings) with Xcompose.  Something else you had in mind?

Comment: A dead key can be used like this: if I assign _g_ as a dead key, it is possible to produce _ǒ_ by pressing _g_ and _o_ respectively (depending on how it is mapped). <br/>
I have no idea how I can handle it using a compose key.

Comment: Change the mappings in `.Xcompose`.  Just change the dead key mapping you are talking about to use `<Multi_key>` instead of that dead key.  Dead keys and the compose keys are just driven by the mappings, which is why I say that they are basically the same kinds of keys.

Answer (score 0):

I see no sensible way to achieve that. `ibus-m17n` provides input methods as opposed to the XKB keyboard layouts where only a few dead keys are present.

If you don't want to write your own input method, using a compose key is a convenient way to handle it.